# Passing of our friend Brent Longborough

Tags: discussion

It is with great sorrow that I write this thread to inform you of the passing of our dear friend Brent Longborough, on December 6th, 2021. According to his family, he passed with honour and grace, at home in their care, beside him until the very last minutes.

He will be sorely missed.

Rest in peace my friend.

Comment: Interaction with Brent has always been pleasurable. We'll miss him.

Comment: I remember he had a great sense of humour. R.I.P.

Comment: His contributions are here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/344/brent-longborough